# c# BindingSource.List.Add() resets the InnerList instead of actually adding anything

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I have two BindingSources in my project that are bound to two different DataGridViews. In the Form constructor I am creating two instances of Refresher class

```
class Refresher
{
    readonly MainForm form;
    BindingSource bindingSource;
    DbType dbType;
    Thread refreshThread;

    public Refresher(MainForm form, BindingSource bindingSource, DbType dbType)
    {
        this.form = form;
        this.bindingSource = bindingSource;
        this.dbType = dbType;

        refreshThread = new Thread(Refresh);
        refreshThread.Name = dbType.ToString() + " refresh thread";
        refreshThread.Start();
    }

    async void Refresh()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (dbType == DbType.Worker)
                FillData(await HttpQueries.GetWorkerList(form.Client));
            else if (dbType == DbType.Job)
                FillData(await HttpQueries.GetJobListAsync(form.Client));
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }
    }

    void FillData<T>(List<T> data)
        where T : IModel
    {
        form.InvokeEx(f => bindingSource.List.Clear());

        foreach (T d in data)
            form.InvokeEx(f => bindingSource.List.Add(d));
    }
}
```

When the application starts running everything is OK and both BindingSources are filled correctly but after one cycle second BindingSource resets and doesn't get new data. When I tried to figure it out using ListChanged event it appeared that each time I call Add method on a second BindingSource ResetList occured instead of ItemAdded. The problem doesn't appear on a first BindingSource.

Comment: The problem was fixed by changing bindingSource.List.Add(d) to bindingSource.Add(d) though it doesn't explain why I encountering that problem

Comment: This is a terrible solution. You have a zombie thread. You should just use a `Timer`. Specifically the Windows Forms Timer that will marshall to the UI thread for you. It's disposable so you can clean up easily.

Comment: @Enigmativity, you mean calling Refresh as timer ticks instead of infinitely running it in a while loop?

Comment: I mean just us a Timer to fill your data. Kill the `Refresh` method entirely.

Comment: @Enigmativity, I still need to assign a handler to tick event where the data from WebAPI will be retrieved which is basically done in `Refresh` method

Comment: Without the `while` loop and the `Sleep`.

Comment: @Enigmativity this is the very thing I meant. Didn't mean to confuse you. This approach seems to be a good idea I'll try it out. Thank you.